# Copy Function in C not creating matching Checksums

Tags: c, openssl, md5

I written a simple copy program that copies a file and generates an MD5, It runs and generates the MD5 correctly.

However when verifying the file generated by the copy function it does not match the source MD5. I can't see any reason for this in my code, can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 512

int secure_copy(char *filepath, char *destpath);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    secure_copy(argv[1], argv[2]);
    return 0;
}

int secure_copy(char *filepath, char *destpath) {
    FILE *src, *dest;
    src = fopen(filepath, "r");
    assert(src != NULL);

    dest = fopen(destpath, "w");
    assert(dest != 0);

    MD5_CTX c;
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    ssize_t bytes, out_writer;
    unsigned char out[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    MD5_Init(&c);

    while((bytes = fread(buf, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, src)) != 0) {
        MD5_Update(&c, buf, bytes);
        out_writer = fwrite(buf, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, dest);
        assert(out_writer != 0);
    }

    MD5_Final(out, &c);
    printf("MD5: ");
    for (int i=0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x",  out[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(src);
    fclose(dest);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
$ ./md5speed doc.txt /home/doc.txt
MD5: 4c55e4b9185eece3cc000c4023f8f6fe
```

when verifying the copied file with `md5sum` I get a completely different hash.

```
md5sum doc.txt 
29cb4da30c3e28fdb81463b5f0a76894  doc.txt
```

Though the file still opens and content is uncorrupted.

Comment: You should use `"rb"` and `"wb"` so the file will be binary processed.

Comment: Without binary, your `MD5_Update` will run on data with cr/lf translated. However, the write would add the cr (or lf) again so the resulting file would be OK.

Comment: ahh yes thanks! the combination of those things its working now. Could you explain the effect of replacing the Buffer size with bytes?

Comment: Not relevant to the root problem, but your use of `assert` isn't appropriate. `assert` should be used to detect logical errors in the code, not input/output errors.

Comment: thanks, its just a quick program to test the speed of the function via `/usr/bin/time -v` in the shell

Comment: OT:  regarding; `secure_copy(argv[1], argv[2]);`  do not access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected number of command line parameters.  If the user did not enter the expected number of command line parameters, then output to `stderr` a USAGE statement, similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s fileName destPath\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `src = fopen(filepath, "r");`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call: `perror( "fopen failed" );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding:

```
while((bytes = fread(buf, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, src)) != 0)
```

and

```
out_writer = fwrite(buf, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, dest);
```

on the last read, the amount read can be less than BUFFER_SIZE so should always use `bytes` variable for the number of bytes to write.

Also, certain errors can occur when calling `fread()` and/or `fwrite()`  Such errors are indicated by negative values (and/or values less than the 3rd parameter to those functions)  in the returned variables (bytes, outwriter).  The code, to be robust, must be checking those values and handling any errors that occur, including EOF

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, changing the fwrite function to use `bytes` as opposed to `BUFFER_SIZE` combined with changing file operations mode "rb" and "wb" to binary.